# Error with firebase login authentication:

Tags: android, flutter, authentication

so this is the code:

```dart
@override
Future<Either<Failure, UserModel>> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  String email,
  String password,
) async {
  try {
    final UserCredential userCredential =
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    final user = userCredential.user;
    if (user != null) {
      final snapshot =
          await _fireStore.collection(_userCollection).doc(user.uid).get();
      print("THIS IS THE SNAPSHOT DATA $snapshot.data() ");

      if (snapshot.exists) {
        final usermodel =
            UserModel.fromJson(snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
        print("THIS IS THE USERMODEL $UserModel ");
        return Right<Failure, UserModel>(usermodel);
      } else {
        return Left<Failure, UserModel>(
          Failure(message: "No userdata has been found"),
        );
      }
    } else {
      return Left<Failure, UserModel>(
        Failure(message: "User not found"),
      );
    }
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (exception) {
    print("THIS IS THE EXEPTIONcodes: $exception");
    print("THIS IS THE EXEPTIONmessages: $exception");
    return Left<Failure, UserModel>(
      Failure(
        exceptionCode: exception.code,
        message: exception.message,
      ),
    );
  } catch (exception) {
    print("THIS IS THE  NORMAL EXEPTIONcodes: $exception");
    print("THIS IS THE NORMAL  EXEPTIONmessages: $exception");
    return Left<Failure, UserModel>(
      Failure(
        message: exception.toString(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is where the code is being called in the ui and placed in a button:

```dart
void signInWithEmailAndPassword() async {
  setState(
    () {
      formStatus = FormStatus.submissionInProgress;
    },
  );
  final result = await SignInWithEmailAndPasswordUseCase(
    repository: UserRepositoyImplementation(
      userDataSource: UserRemoteDataSourceImplementation(),
    ),
  ).call(
    _emailController.text,
    _passwordController.text,
  );
  result.fold(
    (failure) {
      final exceptionCode = failure.exceptionCode;
      if (exceptionCode == "user-not-found") {
        setState(
          () {
            formStatus = FormStatus.submissionFailure;
          },
        );
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(local(context).userNotFound),
          ),
        );
      } else if (exceptionCode == "invalid-email") {
        setState(
          () {
            formStatus = FormStatus.submissionFailureInvalidCredentials;
          },
        );
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(local(context).invalidEmail),
          ),
        );
      } else if (exceptionCode == "wrong-password") {
        setState(
          () {
            passwordStatus = PasswordStatus.invalid;
          },
        );
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(local(context).wrongPassword),
          ),
        );
      } else if (exceptionCode == "user-disabled") {
        setState(
          () {
            formStatus = FormStatus.submissionFailureUserDisabled;
          },
        );
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(local(context).userDisabled),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        setState(
          () {
            formStatus = FormStatus.submissionFailure;
          },
        );
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(local(context).anErrorOccured),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
    (user) {
      setState(
        () {
          formStatus = FormStatus.submissionSuccess;
        },
      );
      _userProvider.setUser(user);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(local(context).userloggedInSuccessfully),
        ),
      );
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

and this is the button:

```dart
ElevatedButtonWidget(
  text: local(context).signIn,
  onPressed: signInWithEmailAndPassword,
),
```

and this is the error am getting

```
Logging in as warukelvin54@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token.
Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.
```

Tried asking chatpgt..and also i tried to to add appcheck to firestore and implement it in my code to eleminate the appcheck issue:
so what as